# How to make to linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

Using two linked lists or something similar, I want to add "ABCD", then I want to get "ABDC".

I'm not sure if my code is right, I'm a noob in C.

The code should have pointer and malloc. I made it like this:

```c
struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* newNode(char data)
{
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

struct Node* constructList()
{
    struct Node* first = newNode(1);
    struct Node* second = newNode(2);
    struct Node* third = newNode(3);
    struct Node* forth = newNode(4);
    struct Node* head = first;
    first->next = second;
    second->next = third;
    third->next=forth;
    return head;
}

void printList(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    printf("NULL");
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear for me. Do you want to get an altered linked list? A copy with an element moved to another place? Based on what? Just the moving the last element before the previous (always the last)?

Comment: The easiest way to "get" linked lists is to visualize them by drawing pictures. If you draw very carefully and step-by-step, you can use the drawings as the basis for your code and the expectations while debugging. Follow your code exactly and try to redraw your pictures. When the code deviates from the expected drawing, you've got a bug and you should have a pretty good idea what you needed to do instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine as shown, though it lacks error handling (and why are you using `char` to store integers?).

Do make sure you `free()` the nodes when you are done using them, eg:

```c
void freeList(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    struct Node* next;

    while (ptr)
    {
        next = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = next;
    }
}
```

I would suggest changing `constructList()` to use a loop, eg:

```c
struct Node* constructList()
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **ptr = &head;

    for (int value = 1; value <= 4; ++value)
    {
        *ptr = newNode(value);
        if (*ptr == NULL)
        {
            freeList(head);
            return NULL;
        }
        ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
    }

    return head;
}
```

You could then generalize `constructList()` to take an array of integers, or a string, as input and loop through that input adding a new node for each value.  For example, try this:

```c
struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* newNode(char data)
{
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (node)
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void freeList(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    struct Node* next;

    while (ptr)
    {
        next = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = next;
    }
}

struct Node* constructList(const char *str)
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **ptr = &head;
    char ch;

    if (str)
    {
        while ((ch = *str++) != '\0')
        {
            *ptr = newNode(ch);
            if (*ptr == NULL)
            {
                freeList(head);
                return NULL;
            }
            ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void printList(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("%c -> ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
```

```c
struct Node *list = constructList("ABCD");
printList(list);
freeList(list);
```

Comment: I get the result like this: 65 -> 66 -> 67 -> 68 -> NULL I do not understand why I get this instead ABDC?

Comment: There are two hotdog shops. there are ABCD customer then CD went to anther shop and the wait in queue like D is the first and c is secand , then they wnats to change again so they go the first shop and the queue become ABDC –

Comment: @Javanoob "*I get the result like this*" - that is because you are using `%d` instead of `%c` when passing each `char` to `printf()`. What you are seeing are the ASCII values of the characters. I have updated my answer to include a proper `printList()`

Comment: @Javanoob "*There are two hotdog shops*" - that information should have been presented up front in your original question, not added on after it had been answered. Your original question was about *making* a linked list, not about *manipulating* a list. I suggest you post a new question about that next step.